# Third screen sometimes black after Kubuntu 16.04 upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, 16.04

I recently updated my Kubuntu 15.10 to 16.04. A minor disturbance that occurs since, concerns one of my screens. I have three of them. The left and middle function normally. The right does not work as it should.

Normally all three screens have a background image. The third, right screen also includes an applet showing me a folder content.

Sometimes, when I do a restart or wake the computer, the right screen is suddenly black. But it is not completely dead ... I can continue to place windows in it and see the mouse pointer. Only the applet and the desktop background is gone. When I disable the screen in the system settings and enable it directly after, everything is fine... for a while.

Any idea what could be the problem?

**UPDATE**: I tried to remove the remaining fglrx packages. It didn't work. This is how I checked for existence of the packages:

```
xxx@yyy:~$ dpkg -l | grep fglrx
rc  fglrx                                                       2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2                     amd64        Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators
rc  fglrx-core                                                  2:15.201-0ubuntu2~15.10.2                     amd64        Minimal video driver for the AMD graphics acceler
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx
sudo apt-get remove fglrx-core
```

Both say that these packages can not be removed because they are not installed. I am confused.

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem. Not found how to fix it yet, though for me the source of the problem is likely http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Comment: My problem was that fglrx only got partially removed. Removing fglrx-updates-core fixed my issue.

Comment: Yes, probably there is a connection. BTW I recently had a case where my main screen changed spontaneously from middle to left. I should probably restart the computer many times to test behvior but I am a bit scared that something could happens that can not be fixed.

Comment: I searched my system using "dpkg -l".  I couldn't find the one you mentioned but there are two packes installed containing "fglrx": "fglrx" and "fglrx-core". I wonder if it is safe to remove them...

Comment: I don't know for sure, though strongly suspect you can just remove the proprietary video driver stuff (fglrx). I've removed such drivers plenty of times in the past. And if things go pear shaped, you can always boot in recovery mode and reinstall them via the shell.

Comment: Please see my update.